# how to define if a kernel program is intended to be a module or built-in

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module

I have written a Linux kernel module, which I included in a kernel downloaded from kernel.org. I modified the Kconfig file of the directory where my module will be to include it in the configuration menu.

But when I run `make menuconfig`, I can only select it as built-in, I can't make it run as a module. What determines if a program is intended to be only built-in or only module or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already figured out how to do it.

For a kernel program to be compiled "module only" it must be depending on "m". By example:

```
config FOO
    depends on m
```

This will limit FOO to be module (=m) or disabled (=n).

For more information:
http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt